# Show that $\int_{|z|=1} \frac{e^z}{z^k} dz = \frac{2\pi i}{(k-1)!}$

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence, complex-integration

I'm supposed to show that $$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{e^z}{z^k} dz = \frac{2\pi i}{(k-1)!}$$ where $|z|=1$ is traversed counterclockwise and $k>0$.

We can parametrize this path as $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$ for $t\in [0,2\pi]$. Now I already know that if $n\neq -1$, we have $\int_{\gamma} z^n dz = 0$ by Cauchy's Integral Theorem (and $= 2\pi i$ if $n=-1$).

I also know that $e^z$ converges uniformly on any closed ball $\overline{D_r(0)}$. Lastly, I'm told that $$ \frac{e^z}{z^k} = z^{-k} + z^{1-k}+\frac{z^{2-k}}{2!} + \cdots$$ converges uniformly on any annulus $\{z\in\mathbb{C} \mid r\leq|z|\leq R\}$, where $0<r<R$.

I'm supposed to use all of these elements to calculate the integral, but I'm having a hard time putting all the pieces together.

Comment: Do you know Cauchy Integral Formulas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Cauchy Integral Formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_formula):

$$\oint\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{e^z}{z^k}=\left.\frac{2\pi i}{(k-1)!}\frac{d^{k-1}(e^z)}{dz^{k-1}}\right|_{z=0}=\frac{2\pi i}{(k-1)!}$$

Comment: Can you please explain this a little more?

Comment: Did you check the link I wrote above? This, together with the fact that $\;e^z=(a^z)^{(n)}\;\;\forall\,n\in\Bbb N_0\;$ makes things clear, I think. Otherwise, what exactly you don't understand?

Answer (score 2):

There is one singularity to $\dfrac{e^z}{z^k}$ at $z=0$. The [residue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_%28complex_analysis%29#Example) is the coefficient of the $\dfrac1z$ term of the Laurent expansion:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{e^z}{z^k}
&=\frac1{z^k}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{z^j}{j!}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{z^{j-k}}{j!}
\end{align}
$$
$j-k=-1$ when $j=k-1$, so the coefficient of the $\dfrac1z$ term is $\dfrac1{(k-1)!}$ .

The integral along a contour circling a singularity counterclockwise gets a contribution of $2\pi i$ times the residue from that singularity. That is,
$$
\oint\frac{e^z}{z^k}\mathrm{d}z=2\pi i\frac1{(k-1)!}
$$